# AS3 change only font of TLFTextField

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts

To change font in TLFTextField I need to do something like this:

```
var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
textFormat.font = "NewFontName";
textField.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;
```

and it works ok, but I loose all other previous properties of textField like color, font size or align. How can I overcome this? I don't want new TextFormat, I want to change font only in existing one. I set color and align in fla file and I want to change font in AS code.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach is:

```
var format: TextFormat = textField.defaultTextFormat;
format.font = "Consolas";
textField.setTextFormat(format);
```

Or you can store reference on TextFormat, if you change it often

Comment: I tried that, but each field in defaultTexFormat is null. Maybe that is because I set color and font in fla file?

Comment: Text fields created on the scene, not programmatically?

Comment: it was made in fla, stored in swc. Then created programmatically and added to stage

Comment: I found error: I should use textField.getTextFormat(); not textField.defaultTextFormat